# How to identify odd characters (possibly php "\0") in SQL database?

Tags: php, sql

I've been trying to import a list of questions (in particular the answer set) into the wordpress database. I'm using a wp pro quiz plugin. When I make the questions manually, the database answer data looks like (from phpmyadmin):

[image]

**The problem:**
When I simply copy&paste the content from the box below, it leaves out the boxes, and hence when I import it back as a csv, it doesn't work properly. On the other hand, if I export it as CSV from phpmyadmin and import the same file it works fine (when I open the csv, there are spaces instead of boxes)

Now I want to be able to make csv files to import into this field. **I need to come up with a way to have these boxes included**. I can also try to run and SQL command to include that array, but it seems very complicated with the amount of escaping required. I tried it with the php export below, without success. The php output from export is:

```
$wp_wp_pro_quiz_question = array(
  array('answer_data' => 'a:1:{i:0;O:27:"WpProQuiz_Model_AnswerTypes":7:{s:10:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . '_answer";s:8:"Option 1";s:8:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . '_html";b:0;s:10:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . '_points";i:1;s:11:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . '_correct";b:1;s:14:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . '_sortString";s:0:"";s:18:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . '_sortStringHtml";b:0;s:10:"' . "\0" . '*' . "\0" . '_mapper";N;}}')
);
```

Comment: Can you offer any details regarding the charset that your database/programs are using?  Did you ask for explanations / support on this at wp pro quiz plugin?

Comment: @mickmackusa no I haven't asked, because based on the previous threads, it seems the plugin is no longer supported. I'm using phpmyadmin, using latin1_swedish_ci collation